# Can I replace my development PC displays with a VR headset (part-time) yet?

Tags: ide, virtual-reality, oculus

I'm looking for a VR solution (presumably software for an Oculus or Vive device) that presents 2 to 4 high-resolution development displays. The main requirement is that it provides all the functionality a software developer needs for part-time use.

Although I welcome you to include your favorite solution and note its benefits, as StackOverflow is not for product comparison any solution will answer my question.

It's OK if this isn't suitable for full work-week use, such as concerns about eyestrain from 8 hours of straight use (although severe eyestrain after short use would make it unusable), but it's not OK if I lose key currently-standard functionality commonly used by most developers, such as ability to run multiple displays and snap an IDE to fill one and a browser to fill another, ability to have a high resolution or high virtual resolution, poor text quality, or ability to use a debugger.

I'd prefer one that I can use with a laptop as a mobile solution outside (yes, I know, the headset ruins the beach), but it isn't required.

Does something like that exist?

Comment: hardware recommendations are off topic.

Comment: I'm not looking for a hardware recommendation. I suspect if there is a solution it is a software solution. Per the link provided in your "Close" vote, "software tools commonly used by programmers" are in scope. I suggest that within the next year, perhaps even sooner, this will be a common development tool. Please reconsider your close vote.

Comment: well software recommendations are off topic too: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: also this seems overly opinion based regardless.

Comment: I hear you, but anyone indicating any solution would get me started. I don't know where to look. That is why I mentioned I don't desire recommendations, only proof of a solution.

Comment: Consider this: anyone who already owns one of these platforms and perhaps uses it for development may be able to answer this question authoritatively. I do not personally own the platform, and I can't think of a better community to ask a question about using what is potentially a new "development tool".

Comment: As a side note, there are actual published values on what capabilities are suitable for modern all-day text work, and obvious expectations regarding desktop capabilities. Most of what I see in latest generation HMD is "you can finally almost use this for serious text work". So, still not quite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Virtual Desktop](http://store.steampowered.com/app/382110). The resolution of the Rift & Vive is still a bit low to use this for coding & development but it's got a lot of potential!

Comment: Great! That also led me to BigScreen, and to a comment by one of the device's developers: "[resolution is] why we're trying to keep our focus on videos and video games in the beginning, both of which are totally usable with the CV1. As a side note though, we do already use BigScreen for social productivity, we often do code reviews in there" - http://uploadvr.com/bigscreen-lets-you-share-use-your-entire-pc-desktop-inside-vr/

Comment: The latest update to the Oculus UI (you have to turn on Beta mode), shows that this stuff isn't far away.